# How to have dynamic prefix in angular router?

Tags: angular

In my Angular application two routes `dashboard` and `login`:

```
www.example.com/dashboard
www.example.com/auth/login
```

The routes for it define as:

```
const routes = [
 { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: 'auth', 
   component: AuthShellComponent,
   children: [{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }] 
 }
]
```

But now I need a prefix which is dynamic: `www.example.com/:companyId/...`

```
www.example.com/facebook/dashboard
www.example.com/facebook/auth/login

www.example.com/twitter/dashboard
www.example.com/twitter/auth/login

www.example.com/ -> no company provided so redirect to www.example.com/unknown/auth/login
```

I can do it by given the `:companyId` prefix in each route:

```
const routes = [
 { path: ':companyId/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: ':companyId/auth', 
   component: AuthShellComponent,
   children: [{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }] 
 }
]
```

But doesn't feel right because I also need to know when I don't give a company id to redirect to `unknown`.

The second solution I was thinking is to create empty component that match `:companyId` and inside to have `router-outlet`. but it's feel like wrong because it's empty component.

Is there a way in Angular to have prefix and it will not affected on the routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can just duplicate the paths but with a `redirectTo` when `companyId` is not provided.

```js
const routes = [
 { path: 'dashboard', redirectTo: '/unknown/dashboard' },
 { path: 'auth', redirectTo: '/unknown/auth' },

 { path: ':companyId/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: ':companyId/auth', 
   component: AuthShellComponent,
   children: [{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }] 
 }
]
```

Comment: I need that `companyId` always be the prefix. but to treat it as prefix. not a meaningful part from the url. just a prefix. but to redirect to `unkown` prefix if I don't have any prefix provided

Comment: I've changed the answer then.. maybe it's enough?